# Spring maven project BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, load-time-weaving

I have upgraded to Spring source 3.1.0 and i am not sure why my project can no longer find the

```
ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver
```

I have made sure to add the server runtime libraries in my build path but i still end up with `BeancreationExceptions`. The stack trace:

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2013-01-05 14:58:49,242 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in file [/Users/warz07/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Dugsi_Manager/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [/Users/warz07/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Dugsi_Manager/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver#3834a1c8' of type [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver] while setting bean property 'loadTimeWeaver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver#3834a1c8' defined in file [/Users/warz07/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Dugsi_Manager/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
```

Mainly shows that it has issues with the RelectiveLoadTimeWeaver,

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver#3834a1c8'
```

I was able to once update my server's context.xml and add the InstrumentalLoadtimeWeaver loader but it no longer works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
        <Manager pathname="" />
        -->
    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
             on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
        -->
       <Loader  loaderClass="com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.ltw.TomcatWeavingInsightClassLoader"/>
</Context>
```

EDIT: Full stack trace

```
2013-01-05 15:30:36,647 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in file [/Users/warz07/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Dugsi_Manager/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [/Users/warz07/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Dugsi_Manager/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver#86ecec5' of type [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver] while setting bean property 'loadTimeWeaver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver#86ecec5' defined in file [/Users/warz07/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Dugsi_Manager/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [/Users/warz07/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Dugsi_Manager/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver#86ecec5' of type [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver] while setting bean property 'loadTimeWeaver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver#86ecec5' defined in file [/Users/warz07/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Dugsi_Manager/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver#86ecec5' defined in file [/Users/warz07/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Dugsi_Manager/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method.
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method.
    at org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver.<init>(ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver.java:103)
    at org.springframework.instrument.classloading.ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver.<init>(ReflectiveLoadTimeWeaver.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
```

Comment: any reason for voting this down.

Comment: you may have any other dependency between you jars. I mean that when you upgdare your Spring library, this new library depends to any other jars which should be upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception shows that your application was loaded by Tomcat's own `WebappClassLoader`, rather than Spring's `TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader` - so your Tomcat configuration might have failed. Maybe you should try putting `loaderClass` attribute under the `<Loader>` element like this:

```
<Context path="/your-application">
    <Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>
</Context>
```

as explained [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-environments).